# AuthGuard prevents Angular Material from loading fully

Tags: angular-material, ionic4

I am working on adding an AuthGuard to my Ionic 4 project. The guard checks if the user is logged in, if true the user continues to the home page, if false the user is redirected to the login page. The problem is when the user is redirected to the login page because of the guard the Angular Material label does not work correct. When the login page is visited without involving the guard everything works correctly.

AuthGuard service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      private user: UserService) { 

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

                if (user) {

                    // User is signed in.

                    resolve(true);

                } else {

                    // No user is signed in.

                    resolve(false);

                    this.router.navigate(['login']);

                }

            });

        });

    }

}
```

login.page.html

```
<ion-content>

  <div class="blue-background">
    <img src="assets/logo.png" width="33%" height="18.6%" style="display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;"/>
  </div>

    <div class="form_wrapper">
      <div class="form_container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="">

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="height: 40px; margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
              <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
              <input matInput style="min-height: 40px;" type="email" [(ngModel)]="username">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="height: 40px; margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
              <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
              <input matInput style="min-height: 40px;" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
            </mat-form-field>

            <ion-button style="margin-top: 10px; float: right; overflow: auto" fill="clear" size="small" color="dark" (click)="goToForgotPassword()">Forgot password?</ion-button>
            <ion-button style="clear: both; overflow: auto" fill="solid" expand="block" color="dark" (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

[Image of how the fields should work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7jwb.png)

[Image of how the fields work after the AuthGuard redirect. Notice the labels don't float.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmElV.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @RichTillis There are no errors in the console. Leaving the page and returning (like by going to the registration page and back to login) fixes the issue. As if the page doesn't load all imports properly when sent by the AuthGuard.

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem by creating an Ionic app and making a login page with Material and adding a route guard but couldn't reproduce the problem. Do you have a github repo I could check out?